Why is my Ui Gameobject not moving to the Position i give him?
I want to have a clean animation coded per a script and therrfor i create two ui images, and alll works fine besides the images are displayed in bottom left corner. I tried to move it with the help of all Functions Unity gives us for (expect Move Towards because i dont want a animation inside of it).  What am I doing wrong?
using System.Collections;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Rendering;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SceneController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SceneAsset scene;

    public Sprite maskSprite;
    public Material maskMaterial;
    public Material backgroundMaterial;

    private float time;

    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine("AnimationController");
    }

    private Image createMesch(string name, Material material) {
        
        GameObject child = new GameObject(name);
        child.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform);
        Image childMaterial = child.AddComponent<Image>();
        childMaterial.material = material;

        // Copied from the internet. Should Center the Pivot and anchor
        childMaterial.rectTransform.anchorMin = new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f);
        childMaterial.rectTransform.anchorMax = new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f);
        childMaterial.rectTransform.pivot = new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f);

        return childMaterial;

    }

    private IEnumerator AnimationController() {
        Image mask = createMesch("Transition_Mask", backgroundMaterial);
        mask.sprite = maskSprite;
        Image background = createMesch("Transition_Background", maskMaterial);

        //Doesnt work
        background.rectTransform.position = Vector3.zero;

        Vector2 screenSize = new Vector2(Screen.width, Screen.height);
        print(background.rectTransform.position);
        background.rectTransform.sizeDelta = screenSize;
        background.color = Color.black;

        float maskSize = Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(Screen.width, 2) + Mathf.Pow(Screen.height, 2));
        Vector2 targetSize = new Vector2(maskSize, maskSize);



        // yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);


        while (time < 1)
        {
   
            mask.rectTransform.sizeDelta = Vector2.Lerp(targetSize, Vector3.zero, time);
            yield return null;
            time += Time.deltaTime / 0.8f;
        }

  
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
        time = 0;
  
        while (time < 1)
        {
   
            mask.rectTransform.sizeDelta = Vector2.Lerp(Vector2.zero, targetSize, time);
            yield return null;
            time += Time.deltaTime / 0.8f;
        }

    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(scene.name);
    }

}




why are you uysing the rectTransform to try to move it?

normal transform have i tried also but it also didnt worked

try using the Anchored Position from the RectTransform.

nice, worked, thank you so much

Actually it is working - I can see your object's pivot being now at world 0, 0, 0.
this is however probably not what you wanted to achieve ;)
For UI items you want to either go through the RectTransform.anchoredPosition which takes all your pivot and anchor settings into account and basically reflects the position you configure in the RectTransform Inspector.
The alternative would be to calculate the coordinates in pixel space yourself (if using Screenspace Overlay Canvas - otherwise even more complex ^^) using e.g. Camera.ViewportToScreenPoint or similar alternatives and calculate all the offsets and anchoring yourself - then you can go through the Transform.position - by why would anyone want to do that? ;)
